# Link a DataTable Column to a Object.Property

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, datatable

I am currently working on some sort of downloadmanager as part of a bigger project.
For each download I use a custom class `FileTransfer` that is responsible for the download of a single file.

When large quantities of files are downloaded, they are stored in a `List<FileTransfer> transfers` within the `DownloadManager` class.

What I want is a live representation of those downloads in a DataGridView.

I now manually add all `FileTransfer`properties to a DataTable linked to a DataGridView.
This is static though, so the progress needs to be updated manually.

I have created this function:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < transfers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (transfers[i].State == DownloadState.Active)
            {
                DataRow row = null;
                try
                {
                    row = dtTransfers.Select("ID=" + transfers[i].ID)[0];
                }
                catch { }
                if (row != null)
                    row["progress"] = transfers[i].Progress;
            }
        }
```

This is way too dirty, error-prone, too time-consuming, etc.

Is there a way to have to value in the DataTable change automaticly when the FileTransfer.Progress value changes?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to bind the grid directly to `List<FileTransfer>`?

Comment: Never knew this, makes life a lot easier already using a BindingList<FileTransfer>.
Still, I have to manually call BindingList.ResetBindings(); to refresh, but that will probably be easiest running a timer.
Thanks